# CodeIgniter white screen on load (undefined base_url in Loader)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my CodeIgniter install is not loading.  I'm sure all my config files are correct, I even have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` set.

No matter what, I get a blank page.

In my error logs I found this:

> [Wed Apr 27 11:08:15 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Call to undefined function base_url()
>   in
>   /var/www/html/system/libraries/Loader.php
>   on line 255

Has anyone seen this error?

Line 255 is:

```
$CI->dbutil =& new $class();
```

Where `$class` is

```
$class = 'CI_DB_'.$CI->db->dbdriver.'_utility';
```

and `$CI->db->dbdriver` is `'mysqli'`.

I used grep, and couldn't find a call to `base_url` anywhere in the Loader class or Database class.

**EDIT**: After changing some files (including the .htaccess file) and then changing them back, I got a different error:

> The URI you submitted has disallowed
>   characters.

**EDIT 2**: Going to `http://myurl.com` gives a blank page, but `http://myurl.com/controller` gives the "disallowed "characters error.

**EDIT 3**: Apache was running as the wrong user, and my DB settings were wrong.  After fixing those, the site works, but only if `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` is blank.  Otherwise I get the "disallowed "characters error.

**UPDATE**: Solved the issue!  This new server has PHP 5.3, and the other servers have 5.2.  `preg_quote` is different in 5.3, so I had to fix it by following the instructions here: http://davidmichaelthompson.com/2009/09/03/fixed-the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters-error-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a permissions issue over any of the CI library files?

`chown www-data system -R` maybe? Or 777 it just for testing?

Comment: I had the same thought, but all the folders have permissions 775, and files inside have 664.

Comment: This did seem to help.  Well, changing the user apache was running as gave a different error.  A database error, I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here was:

1. Apache was running as the wrong user, and had bad permissions on CI's files
2. PHP 5.3 has a different `preg_quote` than 5.2, the fix is here: http://davidmichaelthompson.com/2009/09/03/fixed-the-uri-you-submitted-has-disallowed-characters-error-codeigniter/
3. Make sure your DB settings are correct

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, i installed latest xamp version and found my site is not working, after research and wasting time i found that.

**I  need to turn on following tag in php.ini file**
short_open_tag=On

Make sure to restart apache after doing this.

Hope this helps, most of these problems are related to php.ini file or fresh installation if your site was already running as other people facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a syntax error.. check if all files are uploaded completely

Comment: I'm re-uploading all the files, let's see if that helps.

Comment: base_url should be located in url_helper.php. make shure you load the helper correctly

Comment: The url helper is auto-loaded.

Comment: obviously not, or not in your loader instance :)

Comment: `base_url` isn't used anywhere inside Loader, at least nowhere obvious.  This same code is on another webserver and works there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `base_url` in your `config.php` (in `application/config/`).  Sounds like the syntax might be messed up or there isn't one defined.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://your_url/';
```

Also:
Which version of CI are you on? I just loaded up my `loader.php` file in my working project and my line 255 is a bit different than yours. `$CI->dbutil =& instantiate_class(new $class());`.. I'm not sure if that is relevant as I don't poke around much in the system folder but it is worth looking at

Comment: That's set correctly.  First thing I set when configuring this.  Even if this isn't set, I still get the same error.

Comment: Try replacing your line with what matches mine. I'm also on 1.7.2.  Backup your loader.php first!

Comment: Adding `instantiate_class` make it display an error!  `Unable to connect to your database server`.  Guess I gotta check those settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace in your autoload.php file with following.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```